# Generated Ebook throws error when trying to read it with ebook readers using Ebooklib

Tags: python-3.x, ebooklib

While the epub is being generated successfully, but when I try to read the epub using readers like Calibre or Sigil. They throw errors like certain files are missing.

Here's my code to generate the epub file:

```
book = epub.EpubBook()
book.set_title(novelName)
book.set_language("en")
book.set_cover('temp.jpg', content=open('temp.jpg','rb').read())
book.set_identifier("test")

for i in authorNames:
    book.add_author(i)
for i in range(1):
    driver.get(chapterLinks[i])
    try:
        content=driver.find_element_by_id('chr-content').get_attribute("innerHTML")
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        driver.close()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
        driver.get(chapterLinks[i])
        content=driver.find_element_by_id('chr-content').get_attribute("innerHTML")
        time.sleep(5)
        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    ads=soup.find("div", class_="ads-holder")
    if(ads!=None):
        ads.decompose()
    print(chapterNames[i], chapterLinks[i])
    chapterName=chapterNames[i].replace("-","")
    c=epub.EpubHtml(title=chapterName,
                   file_name='{}.xhtml'.format(chapterName),
                   lang='en')
    c.set_content(str(soup).encode('utf-8'))
    book.add_item(c)
    chapterList.append(c)

book.toc = chapterList
book.spine = chapterList
book.add_item(epub.EpubNcx())
book.add_item(epub.EpubNav())
epub.write_epub('test.epub', book)
```

and here are the errors:

Calibre :

```
calibre, version 5.20.0
ERROR: Loading book failed: Failed to open the book at C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\PersonalProjects\Novel Grabber\test.epub. Click "Show details" for more info.

Failed to convert book: C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\PersonalProjects\Novel Grabber\test.epub with error:
InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running
on C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\PersonalProjects\Novel Grabber\test.epub
Failed to run pipe worker with command: from calibre.srv.render_book import viewer_main; viewer_main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  File "site.py", line 82, in <module>
  File "site.py", line 77, in main
  File "site.py", line 49, in run_entry_point
  File "calibre\utils\ipc\worker.py", line 197, in main
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "calibre\srv\render_book.py", line 824, in viewer_main
  File "calibre\srv\render_book.py", line 815, in render_for_viewer
  File "calibre\srv\render_book.py", line 793, in render
  File "calibre\srv\render_book.py", line 601, in process_exploded_book
  File "calibre\srv\render_book.py", line 604, in <setcomp>
  File "calibre\ebooks\oeb\polish\container.py", line 561, in has_name_and_is_not_empty
  File "genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\calibre-cache\\ev2\\t\\c0-vdo66nim\\EPUB\\Chapter 2  '
```

Sigil:

`Files exist in epub that are not listed in manifest, they will be ignored`

Does anybody know what could be the cause for this?